# request-promise unable to propagate error

Tags: node.js, ecmascript-6, promise, request-promise

Here is my rp call:

```
function hit() = { 
    return rp(options).then((res) => {
        return res;
    }).catch((err) => {
        console.log("Error occured");
        throw err;
    })
}
```

and a function that calls this function:

```
hit().then( res => {
    console.log(ae_res)
}).error( err => {
    console.err(err) /// code never hits this line
});
```

when i run it, if the rp call was successful, all works well. but if it fails, I never hit the catch() block in the callee function.

I am unable to propagate the original error thrown by the rp call.

Comment: Keep in mind that a 404 or 500 error does not make a rejected promise.  Contacting the server and getting an answer back (any answer) is considered a successful request, even if the answer is a 4xx or 5xx status.  So, 4xx or 5xx status results will still go into the `then()` handler.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You're using `.error` instead of `.catch`.

According to the [Bluebird manual](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/error.html) (which is the type of Promise that [request-promise](https://www.npmjs.com/package/request-promise) returns), `.error` only handles [OperationalErrors](http://bluebirdjs.com/docs/api/operationalerror.html) which are basically errors that reject a Promise without using throw. For errors that were thrown you must use `.catch`:

```
hit().then( res => {
    console.log(ae_res)
}).catch( err => {
    console.err(err)
});
```